# Mongodb update field with set

Tags: mongodb

In mongoDb I have an issue to update an field.

I have a collection called userleavelistin this I have column called **sickLeave**.This column have string value like sickLeave: "10.00". I need to update this field with  subtract some value that is also string "01.00".I have given  below the query I tried. (i.e) **10.00 - 01.00 = 09.00 in the** **sickLeave** **column**

```
db.userleavelist.update({ 
    "userId": ObjectId(5d9fd84d3d598088d2ea5e0d) 
},{ 
    "$inc": { { '$toInt': '$sickLeave' }: -1 } 
})
```

But having issue to achieve this.Someone help me.

Comment: What is the definition of the integer and decimal portions of those strings?  Days and hours?   Weeks and days?   Because the subtraction changes.  I **highly** recommend you change your data model and have a granular integer unit like days be the field value, e.g. `sickLeave: 23`.   Then manipulations become trivial.  Don't drive the output format (e.g. `10.00`) into the database.

Answer (score 0):

As you are having `"10.00"` so `$toInt` won't work. Their documentation says,

> You cannot convert a string value of a float or decimal or non-base10 number (e.g. "-5.0", "0x6400")

For it to work, the string value must be an integer i.e. `"10"`, not `"10.00"`.

[Read More](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/)

I think you should try with [$toDecimal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDecimal/) rather than `$toInt`.

Comment: can you help me to solve that one.since I am new to mongoDb thats why only i asking you